# UNITY_ARCore : localEulerAngles gives always 0 value

Tags: unity-game-engine

Working with ARCore to create compass in UNITY.
Player is AR Core Device:First Person Camera. 
Can anyone solve the problem of getting 0 all the time.
[Click here for Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPQjb.png)

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
public class Compass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage CompassImage;
    public Transform Player;
    public Text CompassDirectionText;

    public void Update()
    {
        CompassImage.uvRect = new Rect(Player.localEulerAngles.y / 360, 0, 1, 1);

        Vector3 forward = Player.transform.forward;

        forward.y = 0;

        float headingAngle = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward).eulerAngles.y;
        headingAngle = 5 * (Mathf.RoundToInt(headingAngle / 5.0f));

        int displayangle;
        displayangle = Mathf.RoundToInt(headingAngle);

        CompassDirectionText.text = headingAngle.ToString ();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your player parented to?

Comment: It is parented to AR Core Device.

Comment: Well it suggests your player is not moving independantly of the AR core device, but with it, so its always 0

Comment: So what can I do about that??

Comment: Youd need to have it move independantly - from the parent... so change how it moves

Comment: I added the screenshot...It is independent.

Comment: that doesnt show it as independent. Either way, it seems its beyond the scope of an SO question

Comment: Did you try `eulerAngles` instead of `localEulerAngles`? Also not sure but possible that the ScreenOverlay canvas causes problems, and does not allow to change the values like you expected. But I don't completely understand what the text etc is supposed to do to be honest

Comment: eulerAngles not working...and text shows the the direction in degrees and RawImage is compass bar to indicate N, S, E, W